# Can I create turn based with real time api game center?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm working on turn based card game and I would like to implement real time game api game center just for reason because with that api every time my iphone founds other iphone and with turn based it founds it from 5 tryes.

Is there any Apple legacy or other reason from which I should not do that or I can do that?

Comment: Your question is not quite understandable. Are you asking if Apple minds developing turn based games working via Game Center? If so the answer is definitely no

Comment: No. There are two types of multiplayer games; turn based and real time games. My question is is there any reason that I sohuld not use real tima game center api for my turn based game?

Comment: I don't think so. However i suppose that there's merely no such thing as real time Game Center api as well as there's no turn based Game Center api. it's only GameKit and that's all, isn't it?

Comment: Look at here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW1 and here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch/ImplementingaTurn-BasedMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH15-SW1 those are links to turn based and real time marches. There is diference in functionality and methods are different.

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right. Game Center has changed since i worked with it. Anyway my personal opinion is there should be no problems